# Custom Exception in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to throw a custom exception when my Insert fails, which violates PK / FK relationship.
Now, LINQ TO SQL throws SQLException, I want to throw a more specific exception like CategoryException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you catch the `SQLException` you can check its `Number` property or navigate to its `Errors` property and check if it contains any `SqlError` with number 547 - that should be constraints violation. If you need details about what constraint was violated and on which table you must really parse the message as @tyrongower mentioned. The pattern for the message is:

```
The %ls statement conflicted with the %ls constraint "%.*ls". The conflict occurred in database "%.*ls", table "%.*ls"%ls%.*ls%ls.
```

Edit:

Depending on the type of application you are developing you should be aware of localization. SQL server can localize its error messages so if you deploy the application to the server using different locale setting your exception message parsing will not work.

Comment: Yes SQL server has large set of predefined errors and it search the error message in `sysmessages` by its number.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to catch the SQLException and parse the message body, then throw your desired custom exception.